# Restore db from backup in SSMS - Amazon RDS SQL Server Error 229

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have just signed up for Amazon Web Services for hosting my ASP.NET MVC 5 app. My app uses 3 databases, 1 from database first approach and 2 from code first approach. For that matter I have created databases from SSMS by connecting to the given server name for RDS and master UserName and Password. But now I want to restore my database first database from my local machine. And when I tried to do so, the following error occured when I pressed add backup from device:

[image: EXECUTE permission]

I have tried giving the `EXECUTE` permission in that database properties but of no use. How can I restore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the backup and restore when using RDS to transfer data into RDS. You'll need to use another means to get the data in there.

> If you have an existing Microsoft SQL Server deployment that you want
>   to move to Amazon RDS, the complexity of your task depends on the size
>   of your database and the types of database objects that you are
>   transferring. For example, a database that contains data sets on the
>   order of gigabytes, along with stored procedures and triggers, is
>   going to be more complicated than a simple database with only a few
>   megabytes of test data and no triggers or stored procedures.
>
> **RDS for SQL Server service does not currently support RESTORE DATABASE
>   ... FROM FILE, because the database and log file backups must be local
>   to the SQL Server instance**. Similarly, FILESTREAM is also not
>   supported at this time.
>
> The BULK INSERT and OPENROWSET(BULK...) statements from the server are
>   not supported import procedures due to their dependency on the
>   ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS permission which is not granted for SQL
>   Server DB instances. Please use the process outlined below to import
>   data to a SQL Server DB instance.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: Thanks. I have done it by copying data into excel file and then make a C# utility to copy data from excel file and seed it into the database. THANKS for ur response